# Identifying files that contain graphics

Tags: filecontents

I have following code in my article for identifying files that contain graphics.

```
‎\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}‎
```

How should I identify graphic files, if I have more than one of such files?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your question? That is a way of including the EPS source (of simple EPS files that can be written using ascii text only) but it isn't suitable for most graphic files but if you do use it you can call the image anything you want, you don't have to call it `example.eps`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have three files, should I repeat this command three times?

Comment: Almost certainly you should not have it at all. `\begin{filecontents}{example.eps}...\end{filecontents}` _creates_ a file `example.eps` by writing out the content of the environment. If you have image files already you do not want to over-write them with characters written from your tex file.

Comment: what do you have between that line and the matching `\end{filecontents*}` it should be the PostScript Source code for your image `example.eps` But most PostScript can not be included this way as it will include binary data not writable by TeX.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have following command between `\begin{filecontents*}` and `\end{filecontents*}`: ‎
gsave‎
‎newpath‎
  ‎20 20 moveto‎
  ‎20 220 lineto‎
  ‎220 220 lineto‎
  ‎220 20 lineto‎
‎closepath‎
‎2 setlinewidth‎
‎gsave‎
  .‎4 setgray fill‎
‎grestore‎
‎stroke‎
‎grestore‎

Comment: What is the purpose of that `filecontents*` environment? Why do you have it there in the first place?

Comment: So it just draws a grey square. and do you `\includegraphics{example.eps}` later in the document (really including a file like this is _very_ rare, are you sure you want to do this at all????)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say but the example comes from Springer

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
```

This is a *very* simple postscript file that produces a square

[image]

The `filecontents` environment doesn't "identify" anything it *creates* the file `example.eps` which you could then include in your document (if you wanted to show a square)

It is not possible to include the source of most PostScript files this way as TeX can not write binary data, and if using pdftex you do not want EPS format at all.

This was an example image used like "lipsum random text" in their example document, included this way to make it easy to distribute as a single file.

You do not want the `filecontents` environment with EPS content *at all* in any real document.